# $pull is not working for array in mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, web-development-server

In mongoDB (Through mongoose), I am trying to remove an element in array of a collection and using $pull operator for that, but it is not working.

Rooms collection in mongoDB

```
{
"_id":"sampleObjectId",
"users": ["email1@example.com", "email2@example.com"]
}
```

Backend code to remove a user (mongoose using Node.js)

```
Rooms.update(
              { _id: "sampleRoomId" },
              {
                $pull: {
                    users: "email1@exmple.com" }
                },
              }
            )
```

Noting happens to collection on running this code, no change happens. code runs with no errors and in output it says `"nModified":0` .
I have no idea how to remove a user from collection.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/f58HFvHkJcC this is working as you expected

Comment: There is a typo in your update document, `email1@exmple.com` instead of `email1@example.com`

Comment: @varman please look into this code [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n16EJVkkYtQ) ,it is not working

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, but. I have just given sample of my real code (code given is not the real one), typo is not the real problem @MontgomeryWatts. Please look into this [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n16EJVkkYtQ)

Comment: `_id` is an ObjectId but you're passing the value as a string. Cast it to an ObjectId like [so](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JpPNgNtySHg)

Comment: I tried with this also, it is working in Mongo Playground but not in my code .

Comment: {
        "n": 1,
        "nModified": 0,
        "opTime": {
            "ts": "6880754585644826625",
            "t": 4
        },
        "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000004",
        "ok": 1,
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": "6880754585644826625",
            "signature": {
                "hash": "oHGadmcbcv4n/jRd6B9vvPYm/2s=",
                "keyId": "6877425517838991363"
            }
        },
        "operationTime": "6880754585644826625"
    }
This is my output

Comment: @Rohitkumar https://mongoplayground.net/p/EtGGLxbeo3J is working, But ObjectId s in data, but you pass String in parameter. I just did with String and working

Comment: @varman you are using string in _id, that is why it is working with string. You can check this [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n16EJVkkYtQ). It is not working here.

Comment: I think there is some error in my code, mongoDB is working fine. I will figure this out. Thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//actual code output from the mongo shell. This is working as expected. check if you given //correct value in object_id query parameter.

> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : "sampleObjectId", "users" : [ "email1@example.com", "email2@example.com" ] }
> db.rooms.update(
... {_id: "sampleObjectId"},
... {$pull:{users:"email1@example.com"}}
... );
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : "sampleObjectId", "users" : [ "email2@example.com" ] }
> db.version();
4.2.6
>
```